# Find last line of multiline label and change colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I m working on multi line text with different colour.The following code to change the first line colour But want to change the last line colour.

```
NSRange rangeOfNewLine = [label.text rangeOfString:@"\n"];
NSRange newRange = NSMakeRange(0, rangeOfNewLine.location);

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
       value:[UIColor redColor]
       range:newRange];
```

Comment: can you add your `label.text`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik...label.text = @"string1 \n string2 \n string3"; the series will be that.

Comment: are you used `label. text.numberOfLines = 0;`

Comment: Yes.It is multiline text with single label.

Comment: @kavithaG Your text is now atributed text so use `textLabel.attributedText = your_attr_str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray* lines = [label.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSString* lastLine = lines.lastObject;
NSRange rangeOfLastLine = [label.text rangeOfString:lastLine];

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
             value:[UIColor redColor]
             range:rangeOfLastLine];
```

Comment: what about the mid string2, your answer only change the last line I mean string3

Comment: The questioner is asking about the last line, no?

Comment: perfect.works as expected..thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
//NSString *myString = @"I have to replace text 'Dr Andrew Murphy, John Smith' ";

NSString *myString = @"Not a member?signin";

 //Create mutable string from original one 
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString]; 

//Fing range of the string you want to change colour
attributeText _label.attributedText = attString;
 //If you need to change colour in more that one place just repeat it 

NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"signin"]; 
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:(63/255.0) green:(163/255.0) blue:(158/255.0) alpha:1.0] range:range];

    //Add it to the label - notice its not text property but it's 
attributeText _label.attributedText = attString;
```